# Is $x=0$ a singular point for $xy'' + (\sin x)y = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When writing the equation in standard form, you get $y'' + (\sin x/x)y = 0$ which suggests that $x = 0$ is a singular point. However, I've seen videos online explaining that $x=0$ is NOT a singular point. For example- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdBrxUAS2cw&list=LL&index=3&t=270s

Which is it?

Is $x=0$ a singular point for $xy'' + (\sin x)y = 0$ or not?

Comment: The coefficient $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ has a removable discontinuity at $x=0$. So, a a practical matter, $x=0$ is not a singular point.

Comment: but general consensus from asking around, that doesnt apply and x=0 is still a singular point? can anyone back this up?

Comment: Yes, where the leading coefficient is zero is a singular point. You divide to check if it is a regular singular point or even a removable singularity.